# Convert Numpy image array to 1px high version

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

**CONTEXT:**

Google has an spritesheet of MNIST data.  They took a `(28, 28, 1)` image and turned it into a `(1, 784, 1)` row of data (784 is 28*28).  They then did this for all 65k images.  So it fits into a nice spritesheet like so:
https://storage.googleapis.com/learnjs-data/model-builder/mnist_images.png

**I'm looking to make my own spritesheet of data.**

I'm using numpy/PIL, so when I get an image converted to numpy, with 3 channels.

**Question:**
How do I just flatten it out and then concatenate that flat image so it turns into an image that is width=784, height=number of images, all in RGB.

**pseudocode here:**

```py
# Load image image
image_data = image.load_img("/path/to.png", target_size=(28, 28))

# Create shape (28, 28, 3)
np_train = np.array(image_data)

# Goal change (28, 28, 3) into (1, 784, 3)
# then add that to some final_image, building to final_image (num_images, 784, 3)

# then 
img = Image.fromarray(final_image)
img=.show # spritesheet of image data for consumption
```

**EDIT:**
The result: https://github.com/GantMan/rps_tfjs_demo/blob/master/spritemaker/makerps.py

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quite need `numpy` to do that, although I don't know if its necessary to use it, but there is a way of doing it with simple Python:

```
from PIL import Image

src_image = Image.open('test_image.png') # Image of size (28,28)

pixels = list(src_image.getdata()) # Get all pixel in 1D array.

dst_image = Image.new('RGB', (1,src_image.size[0] * src_image.size[1])) # Create new image with new size.

dst_image.putdata(pixels) # Place pixels in the new image.

dst_image.save('result.png') # Save the new image.
```

**Example**:

Source image:

[image]

Destination image:

[image]

Comment: Very cool!  I was looking to do horizontal, not vertical, but by inverting the 1 and the other pixel count, I was able to change the dimension the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you question is how to concatenate multiple images into one, where each row represents a single image from the original dataset, then reshape + concatenate should do the trick:

```
# all_images is a list / iterator of 28x28x3 numpy arrays 
final_image = np.concatenate([img.reshape(1, -1, 3) for img in all_images])
```